# Can TFS 2013 Build open a popup on start of build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-process

I wish to open a dialog box in the beginning of a build and use a parameter that will come from the popup dialog.
Is it possible in tfs 2013 builds?

Thanks!

Comment: can you not just populate that parameter from the queue build dialogue?

Comment: I want to open a dialog that will populate such a parameter.
what i want to do is tell the build which solutions to build.

Comment: how are you going to start the build?

Comment: I press "queue new build" in the team explorer

Comment: then why add an additional pop up? just expose a param in the queue build dialogue you will need to have the workspace mappings set as root, which will potentially slow you build time.

Comment: How do i add such parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can queue the build and alter the solution to build by exposing the Projects to build Argument.

Open your template, open the Arguments Tab, and then find the Meta Collection.

[image: selectmeta]

Locate the ProjectsToBuild Argument. change the View this Parameter when: drop down value to

Always Show the parameter. save the template and check in.

[image: Process Parameters Meta dialogue]

when you queue a build goto to the parameters tab and enter the solution you want to build

[image: change param]

You will need to set your source to be root, or map that param as well but i'm not sure if that is possible

Comment: I did what you suggested but it doesnt show.
I get an empty dialog in the parameters tab when queuing a build

Comment: so you populated the 1.Projects value?

Comment: if you populate it in the build definition to a default solution, when you queue the build your default value will be displayed, you can then click on the elipses to choose your solution, but you will have to set the workspace in the build definition to be set to root, which in itself is bad

Comment: You need to install hotfix VS12-KB2898341.exe in order for the parameters to be displayed

Comment: ah ok, was using Update4 last time i was on 2012